# Read lookup value dynamically from list and fill select box

Tags: lookup-column

I have one list with different musical **Genres**, this list is linked as a lookup to the lists **Bands** and **Records**. When I register a new band I set the typical genres played by this band and when registering a new record I register band and genres.

Is there any recommended technique to automatically (and dynamically) read the genres from the Band item and fill the genres list when creating a new record?

I was thinking to create some integration web service that can read genres from bands returning a json and fill the genres list with the help of a javascript. I have the "onchange" functionality in place.

**New Band**

[image: New Band]

**New record**

[image: New record]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are within a standard list form by default there is none. However a combination of jQuery, CEWP web parts could help you reach your goal.

See here for an example http://www.sharepointkings.com/2010/09/sharepoint-cascading-drop-downs-using.html and here http://spcd.codeplex.com/

Do not forget there is always the Listdata.svc that could easily be used from within jQUery and CSOM which could enable easy CAML Query filtering of related items, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg701783.aspx

There is always Marc's jQuery library for Web Services,  for more advanced tricks http://sympmarc.com/tag/jquery-library-for-sharepoint-web-services/